# how to delete the reference to a viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Some files in my xcode project are referring to a viewcontroller that i probably made on the fly by exident and not the the one they should link to.

I got a viewcontroller called "StartViewController" when i try to import the StartViewController.h in xcodes the wrong one gets imported.

[image]

On the right you see the viewcontroller it should link to and on the left the viewcontroller that all other viewcontrollers are referring to for some reason

Comment: open all classes from finder...delete previous one..and then write...it it will not coming then type forcibly ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup the one you need, delete both from project and physically, then return backed up back and try to compile.

Comment: the one its referring right now i doesn't have a physical file because its made on the fly. So there is no file i can delete.

Comment: found it. The file was located on a different location.. thanks for the assistance!